# Symfony2 custom doctrine type not added onload

Tags: php, symfony, enums, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to add a custom enum type on my Symfony2 project.
I used solution 2 found here :
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/mysql-enums.html

And i registered my custum type like this :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types

This work fine with entites, but i also need to access to enum values even if i am not connected to the database.
So, i added a getValues() function in the EnumType abstract class.

```php
public function getValues()
{
    return $this->values;
}
```

Now i can access to enum values like this :

```php
$t = \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getType('enumtypename');
var_dump($t->getValues());
```

But, it seems to only work if a connection to the database is established.
I need to add "$conn = $this->get('database_connection');" before in order to make it to works.
Otherwise, my custom type is not added to the dbal and an exception is thrown :

> Unknown column type "enumtypename" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType().

Is there any way to force symfony to add Types even if i am not accessing to the database ?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Symfony 2 are you using? Which version of doctrine are you using?

Comment: Symfony 2.4.0 & Doctrine 2.4.1